# Binding a skeleton to a new mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, renderer

I am trying to add the skeleton to a new mesh in my scene. The original mesh contains the skeleton and the model moves according to the bone position and rotation. I now have a new mesh without a skeleton. I want to skin this new mesh to this existing skeleton. Below is my code where I copy the bone weights and add the skinned mesh renderer.

It doesn't work. It deforms my new mesh terribly. Just for background, my new mesh is just an x-scaled version of the old mesh without the skeleton attached.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    vertices = mesh.vertices;
    int n = mesh.vertexCount;
    Debug.Log ("vertex count" + n);

    //Bone Weights
    weights=new BoneWeight[mesh.vertexCount];
    weights = mesh.boneWeights;
    Debug.Log ("vertex 2:" + weights [2].weight2 + "vertex 100:" + weights [100].weight0);

    //Renderer
    top = this.transform.Find("Tops").gameObject;
    SkinnedMeshRenderer meshRend = top.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ();

    //Skeleton
    Transform[] originalMeshBones;
    originalMeshBones = meshRend.bones;
    Matrix4x4[] bindPoses = mesh.bindposes;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        bindPoses[i] = originalMeshBones[i].worldToLocalMatrix * transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    }

    //Blend Mesh setting
    tshirt.AddComponent<Animator>();
    tshirt.GetComponent<Animator> ().avatar = humanAvatar;
    tshirt.GetComponent<Animator> ().applyRootMotion = true;


    tshirt = tshirt.transform.Find ("Tops").gameObject;

    //blendMeshRend = tshirt.AddComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ();
    blendMeshRend = tshirt.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ();

    BoneWeight[] blendMeshWeights=new BoneWeight[mesh.vertexCount];
    blendMesh.boneWeights = weights;
    Debug.Log ("vertex 2: " + blendMesh.boneWeights [2].weight2 + "vertex 100:" + blendMesh.boneWeights [100].weight0);

    blendMesh.bindposes = bindPoses;
    Debug.Log ("bind poses 0"+blendMesh.bindposes [7].m00);
    blendMeshRend.bones = originalMeshBones;

    //tshirt.transform.parent = this.transform;
    blendMeshRend.sharedMesh = blendMesh;
    blendMeshRend.rootBone = meshRend.rootBone;
}
```

Comment: To better explain this, I need to change the bone positions of the skeleton in my script at run time. Since I update the skeleton in script, I cannot bind it in a 3D editor before. Now, if I change the joint positions with the new mesh attached, it will further deform the mesh. This is what I want to:

1. Update the bone positions of the skeleton.

2. Bind the new mesh (which correctly matches the new bone positions) to this skeleton

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have the exact same issue